# Redirect grep output to file in server

Tags: shell, grep, sh, expect

I am attempting to write a script that greps for something in a number of servers and appends the output of all of them into a single file. The servers are password protected. I use expect to enter the servers and pass the grep command but I am hoping to get the output of each of them to end up in a single file.

Here is an overview of what I want to do:

`spawn ssh xxx@server1
expect "password: "
send "PASSWORD\r"
expect "$ "
send "grep <something> /some/log/file >> file.txt"
expect "$ "
send "exit\r"`

... then continue doing this in dozens more servers with the output of the grep command appending to file.txt each time. I don't mind where the file.txt actually is. It can be on my local computer or any of the servers.

The best I've come up with would be to put each of these in a file on the server the grep is being done on and then scp all those files to local and appending them all. This seems incredibly wasteful though, so I am looking for a way to send the output to a server or to local from a server.

Answer (score 0):

It would be both easier to automate and more secure if you used public key authentication instead of password authentication to get to the servers. Then you could simply loop over them like this:

```
for host in server1 server2 server3  ...; do
  ssh -n "$host" 'grep <something> /some/log/file'
done >file.txt
```

Since you have password access, you can easily put a public key in `.ssh/authorized_keys` to enable key access first. You can do it with your expect script:

```
spawn ssh xxx@server1
expect "password: "
send "PASSWORD\r"
expect "$ "
send "mkdir -p .ssh\r"
expect "$ "
send "cat >>.ssh/authorized_keys <<EOF"
send "(public key goes here)\r"
send "EOF\r"
expect "$ "
send "chmod 0700 .ssh\r"
expect "$ "
send "chmod 0600 .ssh/authorized_keys\r"
expect "$ "
send "exit\r"
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you **must** use a solution with password-entry, you can append to a file with `expect` with something like:

```
log_user 0                 # to not see the output on screen
set fh [open foo.log a]    # open the file for appending

set servers {user@server user@server2 […]}

foreach s $servers {
    spawn ssh user@server
    […]
    send "command"
    expect "$ " { puts $fh "$expect_out(buffer)"} 
}
close $fh
```

Comment: This works great, could you explain why you use [open foo.log a] rather than just foo.log? Also, what is the meaning of close $fh?